# Use of Stripe payment gateway in django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have installed [dj-strpe](https://github.com/pydanny/dj-stripe) module and register one user without any difficulty i.e., by submitting the form at /payments/ and here dj-stripe register the current user to stripe.com . But what if I want to send card information with the user and want to use it later , However I register the card by following instructions https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms .

But I think this module must contain all this forms already but I don't found any thing in documentation to use them (how ever I find out urls and forms in this module) . So please tell me how I can use those forms in my project , is there any specific tags or urls to submit the forms.

For one instance I used this url /payments/history/ but I didn't show any thing in browser however I have checked the browser console and in response there is some html but browser is blank.

I hope I have explained my question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Go through this link, it may helpful for you. [http://bryanhelmig.com/20-minutes-with-stripe-and-django/](http://bryanhelmig.com/20-minutes-with-stripe-and-django/)